# ZXing on Android: how to set camera in negative mode?

Tags: android, camera, zxing, mode

I want to use zxing in an android project. I have download the code and the example app is running now (ZXingTestActivity). For your information, i am not very familiar with coding native android.

I want to use zxing to scan qr-codes to configurate an application. To avoid confusion between normal qrcodes and configuration qrcodes i want to print inverted/negative qrcodes on screen or paper.

To be able to scan these inverted/negative qrcodes, the camera must be in negative mode. How can i do this? I am not sure where to start, however....

In the ZXingTestActivity.java there is a clicklistener that specify some extra parameters to the IntentIntegrator, for example:

```
private final Button.OnClickListener scanProduct = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZXingTestActivity.this);
      integrator.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 800);
      integrator.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 200);
      integrator.addExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 3000L);
      integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Custom prompt to scan a product");
      integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
    }
  };
```

Is it possible to add camera settings with addExtra and how do i format this? Is it possible? Or is there another way to configurate the camera to inverted/negative mode?

Comment: Can somebody explain why my question is downvoted? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if it completely impossible with ZXing but with ZBar it is possible!

1. First download the ZBar android version on sourceforge:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/
2. Add project to eclipse
3. Open CameraPreview.java
4. Add a private var to the class:

   private Camera.Parameters mCameraParams;
5. Add the following lines after the line: `mCamera = camera;` in the constructor CameraPreview:

   mCameraParams = camera.getParameters();
   mCameraParams.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
   mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParams);
6. That's it! (run the project)

Also think that ZBar is faster to detect damaged barcodes. Is the same as the PC-version i have used in another project and does the job very well. Blink with your eyes and the code is there. No fancy things at all, just good!

Comment: To be clear and repeat the above: yes this is how you can do it in the zxing project too. In any app really.

Answer (score 2):

@Erwinus, here's the code. I hope it's now clear why it is something you have already been completely given in previous comments. More homework and fewer accusations makes SO a happy place.

```
mCameraParams = camera.getParameters();
if (mCameraParams.getSupportedColorEffects().contains(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE) {
  mCameraParams.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
}
mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParams);
```

Comment: I already knew this. And still he don't want to say in which file it is, that is what i want to know! Where is the camera object? Did you read the comments? Why is it so difficult to give me that answer? More homework?????

Comment: How would I know what file to edit in your app? In my app its CameraConfigurationManager.java. You didn't search the source for where Camera.Parameters is used? Its OK being a newbie - and this is among the least competent questions I've seen - but the attitude is weird. I'd cut it out.

Comment: Never mind......... You are the creator of ZXing right? Read the first line of my question: "I want to use zxing in an android project. I have download the code and the example app......" So where is it in the example? I'm using your library..... and your example app ;-)

Comment: You should not be copying and pasting the Android client; please write your own app. It is not an "example". If you've copied part of it, OK: I already pointed you to `CameraConfigurationManager.java`. Short of typing on your keyboard, I can't help you further. I am sorry I answered this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is not needed to say sorry. I'm not copying your app, i'm trying to learn, that's all, that is why i using your example to figure out how it works. When i know how it works, i setup a new project. It is in the first line of the question: "I want to use....". There are allot of files in the lib and did not know where to look at. Thank you, that was all i want to know. But never thought that a question could be that difficult, it is a weird experience to me.

Comment: changed the CameraConfigurationManager.java file in android\src\com\google\zxing\client\android\camera\ but nothing happens, it feels like i'm wasting my time. Sorry to say, too many files, too many options, very frustrating. The AS3 version is better to understand, but is not updated to the latest version. Will there ever be a newer version of the AS3 version that i can use it in Flash Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry there's not a way to do this via `Intent`. A clean patch adding this as an option would be attractive to commit. The only gotcha is that the camera must support the "negative" mode. Then it's trivial (you can see this behavior as a selectable option in [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android)). Otherwise you have to flip the image yourself. Not hard, but takes a bit of code and CPU cycles.

Comment: See my answer, is that also possible with ZXing?

Comment: Sure, that is what I refer to here. It only works when the camera supports this mode.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how to do this instead of telling me that it must be an option and must be supported by the camera? It would be nice if you explain how to detect the camera supports this mode. You said: Sorry there's not a way to do this via Intent. Okay i understand but when it is not possible via intent, can you give me some direction to archive my goal?

Comment: It's a more efficient use of SO if you research the answer already given. You'd quickly find the method `getSupportedColorEffects()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedColorEffects()).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. Like i said in my question:  i am not very familiar with coding native android. Can you please tell me where i can find the camera object in ZXing?

Comment: You don't want to tell me? Is it that you want that i buy your app?

Comment: I'm confused. The underlying app is free and open source. I am not sure how many more ways to tell you exactly how to do this in the open source app. Your answer below is exactly how you do it, how I did it, which is what I said here. I further told you how to tell whether the camera supports it. It is 5 lines of code, of which you have written 3. Did you even read the link?

Comment: I don't understand your confused. I have a simple question (simple for you to answer) and each time you don't give me the answer in code. What is the idea behind that? I just want to now in which file the camera object is because i cannot find it, that's all i want to know. I already find out how to change the camera object in ZBar, i think it must go in similar way. I really appreciate your work and previous explanations, i really do. If you can tell me where it is then i go. I'm sorry that you are confused, that's not my intention.

Comment: And still he don't want to say in which file it is, that is what i want to know!